# How can i forward a client request in Phoenix framework, acting as a proxy?

Tags: proxy, http-proxy, phoenix-framework

I would like to act as a proxy for certain requests in my application.
For example: if a user requests the link "http://myapp/proxy" , I would like to forward the request to an external website and retrieve the response to the user. 
The problem here is that I don't want to do URL redirection, but I would like to forward the client requests, acting on behalf of the user.

How can I do it using Phoenix framework?

Comment: You will need to read the incoming data from the Plug connection (see http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html) and then do a request using an HTTP Client, like https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison.

Comment: Thanks!! ;) it works!

Comment: i'm trying to do the same thing, the part i'm still missing is how to "return" (stream?) the data from the HTTP client back to the client?

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness, here's what i did:

```
case HTTPoison.get(url) do
    { :ok, response } -> conn |> put_resp_content_type(response.headers["Content-Type"]) |> send_resp(response.status_code, response.body)
    { :error, _error } -> conn |> put_status(:bad_gateway) |> render(AssetsProxy.ErrorView, "502.html")
  end
```

still very new to the whole elixir/phoenix party, so i'm sure there's stuff to improve on. e.g. it does not handle redirects correctly.

Comment: You'd have to transpose all the attributes of conn to the proper HTTPoison methods, which should be the method, host, headers and body

Comment: What if you want to send another types of request?

Answer (score 0):

To "return" the data back to the client, the code is the following:

```
HTTPoison.start
response = HTTPoison.post!(url, body, [])

conn |> halt   |>
html  response.body
```